# Intercepting only void return calls using AspectJ

Tags: aspectj, void

I have a trace aspect that should log:

- Entering
- Exiting (return type is void)
- Returning [returned object]
- Throwinig [Exception message]

I am having problems with the second. How do I create an advice for this case without double-logging all exits that also return something as is the case now when I have one @After advice and one @AfterReturning(value = "publicMethodCall()", returning = "o"). Can I somehow have the @AfterReturning advice be called for void returns and still retrieving its value when it returns are non-void (probably not as it would be impossible to tell if the method returned null or if the return type was void).

I a, guessing this should be easy but I can't see it...

Comment: Actually, the @AfterReturning(value = "publicMethodCall()", returning = "o") does intercept void returns as well (although not constructor "returns") which means I am forced to use !jp.getSignature().toLongString().contains(" void ") or similar to determine whether null was returned or whether the return type was void. Any better solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be simpler to use around advice.  One pointcut/advice pair.  (I am using the code style aspectj syntax here because I prefer it).  I can translate to @AspectJ style if you need:

```
Object around() : publicMethodCall() {
  try {
    Object result = proceed();
    log(result, thisJoinPoint);
    return result;
  } catch (Throwable t) {
    log(t, thisJoinPoint);
    throw t;
  }
}
```

Here, if your method returns void, then the `result` will be `null`.

Comment: Yes, but how do I determine if the returned value is null or if the method return type is void without string parsing the jp.getSignature().toLongString() value? I need to distinguish between the two cases.

Comment: you can do something like ((MethodSignature) jp.getSignature()).getReturnType();

You know that it will be a method signature based on the pointcut

Comment: Hi! Could you, please, translate it to @AspectJ style?